# Transmission opening up without torrents

Tags: 15.04, transmission

I am running the following command to open Transmission:

```
transmission-gtk
```

But all i get is the UI. It somehow opens up and instance of Transmission without the torrents. Do i need to pass in some flags to start a Transmission with the torrents? Also, opening this way does not show the indicator in the Ubuntu menu bar.

**UPDATE :**  I'm running this through a cron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [`transmission-gtk` manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/en/man1/transmission-gtk.1.html) for Vivid:

```
FILES
     ~/.config/transmission
             The config-dir used when neither [TRANSMISSION_HOME] nor [-g] is
             specified.
```

So in order to load the configuration files `transmission-gtk` first checks the `$TRANSMISSION_HOME` environment variable, then falls back to checking the `-g` option and finally falls back to loading the configuration files from the `~/.config/transmission` directory.

Since you're running this as a Cron job, use the `-g` option to specify the full path to Transmission's configuration folder:

```
transmission-gtk -g /home/username/.config/transmission
```

Comment: Thanks. Running the command from terminal opens up with torrents correctly but when i run a cron and try the same command in script,it shows up empty window.

Comment: @hussain Use the full path if you are using this in a cron: `transmission-gtk -g /home/username/.config/transmission`. Was the problem with cron since from the start? Or this is another question? Just to adapt my answer.

Comment: Ok. I updated the question to make it cron specific. I update to use absolute path(lesson learned :D ) and it shows torrents but still no indicator in top Ubuntu bar.

Comment: but what about the indicator? can i somehow show that? any idea what triggers that?

Comment: @hussain Is this your user's crontab? Or root's crontab?

Comment: it's user's crontab not root

Comment: @hussain The problem is as far as I know (although I don't know almost anything about Cron) that normal environment variables are not set while executing a Cron job; this is totally a shot in the dark, but try to set `DISPLAY=:0` in the crontab

Comment: @hussain Or better, run Transmission like this: `DISPLAY=:0 transmission-gtk -g /home/user/.config/transmission`. If you have a particular arrangement of monitors check first the value of `$DISPLAY` in the monitor you want to open Transmission in by running `echo $DISPLAY`

Comment: i already have set it up just like your last comment. UI does not show up without `DISPLAY=:0`

Comment: @hussain Another shot in the dark, try `DISPLAY:0.0 [...]`

Comment: No, same result. Anyways, i think i have enough to go on and figure out indicator issue myself. Let's just close this thread.